# Show that if $f$ is analytic in $|z| \leq 1$, there must be some positive integer $n$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n}) \neq \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know this question was posted before, but i have some different question.

Here is my solution:
Assume a contradiction that $f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) = \left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)$ for all $n$. Consider $g(z) = \dfrac{z}{1+z}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, now consider $$h(z) = f(z) - g(z)$$

Note that since $f,g$ are both analytic throughout $B(0,1)$, we thus have $h$ to be analytic throughout $B(0,1)$ as well. Consider a sequence $z_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$ in $B(0,1)$. We verify that $h(z_n) = f(z_n)-g(z_n) = 0$ and $0$ is an accumulation point in $B(0,1)$. Then by uniqueness theorem, $h(z) = 0$ throughout $B(0,1)$.

**Hence it follows that $$f(z) = g(z)$$ for all $z$ in $B(0,1)$. But since $f(z)$ was given to be analytic at $z=-1$, this cannot happen as $\dfrac{z}{z+1}$ is not continuous at $-1$.**

The last paragraph was followed from the model solution, in which i did not understand. Because according to what i understand, $f(z) = \dfrac{z}{z+1}$ agree on the the open ball $|z| < 1$. So that does not mean they agree on the closed ball $\overline{B(0,1)}$. Hence i am confused as to how $z=-1$ comes into play?

Can someone help me?

Comment: As $f$ and $g$ agree on the open unit disc, they also agree on the closed unit disc, by continuity.

Comment: May i know which theorem is that, for all i know i am looking at the uniqueness theorem of analytic functions and it doesnt tell me they will agree on the closed unit disc.

Comment: $f$ analytic on $\overline{B(0,1)}$ means it's analytic on a larger open set so is continuous on the closed disc (analytic implies continuous). Also $z/(1+z)$ is continuous on the closed disc (save at $z=-1$).

Comment: Since analyticity at a point makes use of the neighborhood of that point, $f$ analytic on $|z| \le 1$ means $f$ is analytic on some **open** $U$ containing $|z| \le 1$ (indeed $U$ must contain an open disk $|z| < r$ for some $r > 1$). In particular $f$ is bounded and continuous and analytic at $z=-1$, but $\frac{z}{z+1}$ is not.

Comment: @user1952009 thank you, i understood now

Comment: I see that $f(-1)$ doesnt exists, so $f$ cannot be discontinuous at $z=-1$.

Comment: @Masacroso What is not true ? Do you know what is the analytic continuation ? And $1/z$ is not continuous at $z=0$, no matter it is defined there or not.